# Ubuntu 18.04: Macbook Pro Won't Boot with Intel Integrated GPU?

Tags: boot, 18.04, intel-graphics, amd-graphics, macbook-pro

I've got an old 2011 Macbook Pro running Ubuntu 18.04 that has integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000, as well discrete AMD Radeon HD 6750M graphics. The discrete AMD card is basically dead (Google "Radeongate" for why that is), so I'm trying to recycle the Mac as a simple web browsing machine that can at least play HD videos using the integrated graphics alone. The problem is, unless I disable **both** GPUs with "nomodeset" in the GRUB kernel boot parameters, the thing will not boot. If I leave the parameters at their default "quiet splash", I end up with a blank purple screen that I can still SSH into to shutoff. If I add "radeon.modeset=0" to the parameters, I end up at the list of boot processes and checks, but it freezes at some arbitrary line, and again, I can SSH into it still to turn it off. In both the previous cases, I also can't switch to a command-line-only tty session. The only way to boot is if I add "nomodeset" to the parameters, and I end up with Ubuntu running on llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits).

I'm fairly certain the Intel i915 driver provided with Ubuntu is installed correctly (it's shown in lsmod), and since Intel discontinued their graphics driver update tool, I don't know of anywhere else I could get another driver. I also have no reason to believe that the iGPU is also dead since before installing Ubuntu, I had a short success getting into OS X with the iGPU.
I've got some logging information that I thought would be useful based on other similar posts I found for the 3 scenarios I described above.

### Adding "nomodeset" to Kernel Boot Parameters (Uses Neither GPU, Boots)

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL

OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 6.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.2.0-devel
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.1 Mesa 18.2.0-devel
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.40
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.2.0-devel
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sudo lshw -c video

  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:b0800000-b081ffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:b0820000-b083ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0000000-b03fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:3000(size=64)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sudo lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
```

### Adding "radeon.modeset=0" to Kernel Boot Parameters (Uses iGPU, Frozen Boot Screen)

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL

libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sudo lshw -c video

  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:b0800000-b081ffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:b0820000-b083ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:b0000000-b03fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:3000(size=64)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sudo lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
```

### Default Kernel Boot Parameters (Uses iGPU, Stuck on Blank Purple Screen)

```
glxinfo | grep OpenGL

libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
Error: couldn't find RGB GLX visual or fbconfig

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sudo lshw -c video

  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:b0800000-b081ffff ioport:2000(size=256) memory:b0820000-b083ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:b0000000-b03fffff memory:a0000000-afffffff ioport:3000(size=64)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

sudo lspci | grep VGA

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M]
```

### Also, lsmod Results

```
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 77824  4
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 24576  0
snd_hda_codec_cirrus    20480  1
btusb                  45056  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
btintel                16384  1 btusb
bluetooth             548864  31 btrtl,btintel,bnep,btbcm,rfcomm,btusb
uvcvideo               86016  0
ecdh_generic           24576  1 bluetooth
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
bcm5974                16384  0
videobuf2_core         40960  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              184320  3 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
media                  40960  2 uvcvideo,videodev
applesmc               20480  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    73728  1 snd_hda_codec_cirrus
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_intel          40960  8
snd_hda_codec         126976  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_cirrus
input_polldev          16384  1 applesmc
snd_hda_core           81920  5 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_cirrus
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
wl                   6447104  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
acpi_als               16384  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 acpi_als
sbs                    20480  0
snd_pcm                98304  4 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core,snd_hda_codec_hdmi
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
mei_me                 40960  0
cfg80211              622592  1 wl
industrialio           69632  2 acpi_als,kfifo_buf
snd_seq                65536  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
sbshc                  16384  1 sbs
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             204800  0
kvm                   593920  1 kvm_intel
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
pcbc                   16384  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
aesni_intel           188416  0
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  3 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        16384  0
apple_gmux             20480  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
snd                    81920  27 snd_hda_intel,snd_hwdep,snd_seq,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_cirrus,snd_seq_device,snd_pcm
soundcore              16384  1 snd
shpchp                 36864  0
mac_hid                16384  0
apple_bl               16384  1 apple_gmux
sch_fq_codel           20480  3
parport_pc             36864  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,parport_pc,ppdev
ip_tables              28672  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
hid_apple              16384  0
hid_appleir            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  4 hid_appleir,hid_generic,usbhid,hid_apple
i915                 1617920  0
ttm                   106496  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
drm_kms_helper        167936  1 i915
tg3                   167936  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
firewire_ohci          40960  0
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  2
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
libahci                32768  1 ahci
ptp                    20480  1 tg3
sdhci_pci              28672  0
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
drm                   401408  3 i915,ttm,drm_kms_helper
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
pps_core               20480  1 ptp
sdhci                  49152  1 sdhci_pci
thunderbolt           118784  0
video                  40960  2 apple_gmux,i915
```

So does anyone have any ideas why I can't boot using just the iGPU? Please let me know if I left out any important information needed to help solve this, and thanks in advance for your help!